# Insert HTML/php file into SharePoint 2010 master page

Tags: php, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been searching high and low for an answer to this. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

In a SharePoint 2010 master page, how can I call to a centralized file to load code into the master page? My problem -- I've been tasked with creating a way of having navigation load from one central file to be loaded on several different site collections's master pages. This needs to be html, and not the typical SP navigation, as I'm using a jquery megamenu solution.

I got this to successfully load with javascript but maybe because I'm using a megamenu with jquery dropdown, it slowed the page load to a complete crawl. I considered a CEWP but don't think i'll be able to strip out all the CSS to make it load seamlessly - although this might be the way I have to go.

I'm hoping for a workaround with the php include command. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run PHP on a SharePoint site.  You can however, create a web part or other C# code to include on your master page to render your menu.  A jQuery solution should work as well.  If it's slowing your page load down, maybe you should create your menu after the document is ready.

Comment: Thank you Robbert for your answer.